# finding intersection and union of indexed family of subsets of real number

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I'm guessing that the intersection would be empty set and union would be set of real number. How would I be able to prove it, using Archimedean Property if necessary?

Comment: I think your guess is right; a real number would be in the intersection if it would be in all $A_t$ and in the union if it would be in at least one $A_t$

Comment: In this exercise, using the Archimedean property is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the definition of intersection and union and apply them directly. *When in doubt, always look at the relevant definition(s).*

**Intersection:**

> $$\require{color}\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i = \{x : x \in A_i {\color{blue}\text{ for all }} i\} $$

**Union:**

> $$ \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i = \{x : x \in A_i {\color{blue}\text{ for some }} i\} $$

What does it mean for $x \in A_t$ for all $t$? It means $x \ge t$ for all $t$ because "$x \in A_t$" is equivalent to "$x \ge t$." Likewise, $x \in A_t$ for some $t$ means $x \ge t$ for some $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove, in the first case, that for any real number $x$, that $x\not\in\bigcap A_t$.

In the second case,  prove an arbitrary real $x$ is an element of the union.  That is, there is $t$ such that $x\ge t$.  For instance,  $t=x-1$.